# Boost mutexes and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, boost, mutex

I have a few singleton classes with some extra functions which are run in separate thread. The structure looks like:

```
class Singleton
{
   private:
      boost::mutex mMutex;
      std::vector<std::string> mMessages;

   public:
      void AddMessage(const std::string &msg)
      {
         mMutex.lock();
         mMessages.push_back(msg);
         mMutex.unlock();
      }

      void Sender()
      {
          while (true) {
             mMutex.lock();
             for (size_t i = 0; i < mMessages.size(); ++i)
             {
                 // Do something with mMessages[i]
             }
             mMutex.unlock();
          }
      }
};

...

int main()
{
   Singleton *handle;
   handle = Singleton::instance();
   boost::thread sender(boost::bind(&Singleton::Sender, handle));

   ... app cycle ...
}
```

Sometimes it fails with error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of

```
'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost::lock_error
Aborted
```

What could it be and what's the best why to find out the reason of assert?

Comment: as a side note, you should use locks like boost::scoped_lock instead of just locking mutexes

Comment: your Sender() function is spinning without doing anything if mMessages is empty. You should use a condition variable here to let the thread block until there is something to do.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki yeah, there is sleeping of the thread. I just decided not to show this in example

Comment: Do as Nikko says, or else if your code throws an exception you will be in big trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be that you did **not** create the object `Singleton`! So the mutex is not created either.

Try:

```
int main()
{
   Singleton handle; //object, not pointer
   boost::thread sender(boost::bind(&Singleton::Sender, &handle));
   ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. No, after creating handle I initialize it.